# Wp7 app got rejected in marketplace (cannot be tested for compliance)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have pasted below the screen shot of the error report which I received:

> The application cannot be tested for compilance for wp7 application certification requirements due to geographic,hardware or software limitations.Please provide valid test account credentials with resubmission
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. Double check that the capabilities required by your application are declared correctly.
> 2. Avoid hard-coded logic based on the orginal Product ID.If your application design requires using logic based on a product id,use the windows phone marketplace assigned non-volatile product id instead.

Comment: just a few questions... Are you doing any of what it is saying? Are you hardcoding anything? Are you using any 3rd party APIs that require a login to work?

Comment: The only answer that could be given here, would be to restate the error message, as we cannot access your source code and determine which criteria has caused validation to fail

Comment: there is no screenshot shown! Please update your question.

Comment: The report should also have included some detailed information from the person who did the certification test which includes more specific information. Check this.

Comment: You should first tell us what your app is doing, then we might be able to tell you what is wrong. Usually the tester feedback gives a pretty good indication of where something is wrong

Comment: @ Dubbridge in my app i am not hardocing anything which uses product ID. My app requires a registration to proceed forward. For that sunbcriber id and password is needed. Our client only uploaded the app for certification in market place. He did not give the subscriber id and password ( which i came to know later only). So i suppose that was the reason why the app got rejected.     
@ Lacey i am new to this forum. so when i tried to paste the screen shot they told like for pasting the image "more points are needed,something like that" .So instead then i typed the comments which the testr gave

Comment: @ Tom these were the comments which i got.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that might help:

- If your app requires credentials to work, you can create a dummy user for testing purposes, and provide these credentials when submitting the app to the marketplace.
- About the capabilities, you should declare all the phone features that your application uses. This is done through the Properties/WMAppManifest.xml file in your project. You should check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for extended information on each capability. By default, all the features are declared, so you should remove the features that you won't be using.

Comment: @ alfonso: Actually i commited both the mistakes which you mentioned here. Any way have made the chnages which you suggested. Thanks.